# Using ng-options syntax with object index instead of object name

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-options

I am using Angular 1 and have been trying to display the drop down list values using ng-options directive and the only one that could work for me is :

```
<selectdata-ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in JSON.ObjectName.ListValues"></select>
```

Because of the way my JSON is generated, I will need to display any number of the drop downs iteratively. So the only way to make the above syntax work is to assign an index based value Example: **index[0]** in place of the **ListValues** . Something like this:

```
<select data-ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in JSON.ObjectName.index[0]">
```

My JSON Object is of the format:

```
{
    "JSON": {
        "ObjectName": {
            "ItemValues": {
                "0000": "County",
                "0100": "City",
                "0200": "State",
                "0300": "Region",
                "0400": "Country"
            },
            "AreaValues": {
                "1111": "Metro",
                "11AA": "Subway",
                "2222": "Bus"
                "22BB": "Transit"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried assigning the JSON to a scope object in my controller and was trying to display on my page, but if i were to do this for any number of drop downs, that approach wouldn't work efficiently.

My only other option is to do this using the JSON index

Would this approach work?
Should I be using custom directives?
Is there a better way of tackling this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

One option that is there would be to attach the object directly to the controller and not the $scope object in angular.

```js
var this = ctrl;

ctrl.object //this should attach the object to he scope of the controller.
```

```html
   <select id="idName" name="name" ng-model"ctrl.object.ListValues" data-ng-options="key as key for (key,value) in ctrl.objectName.ListValues"></select>
```

You could use something like the above code access each of the options and display them to the select element in the html.

I am new to angular, so I apologize if this isn't correct, but I have done something like this with ngOptions before and this solution seems to work well in the scenario your described.

Comment: Also, what logic is being provided by your controller? There are a lot of things that could be effecting whether or not you can display the information as intended.